# replace commas to decimal points in DataFrame columns to make them numeric

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([["one", 1.2, "", "4,3"],
   ["two","1,7", "2,4", 0.55],
   ["three","", 5.4, "3,9"]], 
   columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

How can I replace the commas in the columns b to d to points and make these columns numeric?
Column a (or any number of leading columns) should be retained untouched (can contain commas as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re    

for col in ['b', 'c', 'd']:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col].apply(lambda x: re.sub(',', '.', str(x))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do the job with: for col in df.columns[6:]:

Answer (score 1):

### **Just an update on this topic:**

pandas now added a `replace` method, so we can avoid the use of lambda.

```
df.replace(to_replace=",", value=".", regex=True)
```